# Problem with installation from usb

Tags: usb-drive

I have a problem with booting from pendrive for installation. Photo screens attached
[image]

Comment: Did you verify your download? That's where I'd start with this error. Tip: If you download it via torrent, it'll automatically verify it for you.

Comment: I downloaded from the official website https://elementary.io/pl/ and paid the tax

Comment: Downloads, especially of large files, can become corrupted. So, you'll want to verify your download. Directions to verify the download are [here](https://elementary.io/pl/docs/installation#choose-operating-system).

Comment: Hello
I checked the checksum and everything is ok.
I think there are some settings in the BIOS but my knowledge is not sufficient.

Comment: You can try looking for something like 'legacy bios'.

Comment: Hello
It all started working when I disconnected the ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB JMicron Generic SCSI Disk Device from my computer. I have no idea why this error occurs with this drive, regardless of whether the drive was connected at the CD site or externally via USB. Now I have a Toshiba inside my laptop and this problem is not there. Also thanks and the problem has been solved.

Comment: You can write up your own answer and accept it so that others know to check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem described may occur when old models of drives are connected to the computer. In my case, after disconnecting, the problem does not occur.